# Bundle install command error. Ruby version is 2.2.0 and Rails version is 4.1.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Error running bundle install command. Ruby version is 2.2.0 and Rails version is 4.1.8. Environment is Apple Mac OS Sierra (10.12.5)

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
```

In Gemfile:
    composite_primary_keys (= 7.0.15) was resolved to 7.0.15, which depends on
      activerecord (~> 4.1.7)

```
rails (= 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.4, which depends on
  activerecord (= 4.2.4)
```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rack (~> 1.5.3)

```
omniauth was resolved to 1.7.1, which depends on
  rack (< 3, >= 1.6.2)
```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.4)

```
commands was resolved to 0.2.1, which depends on
  rails (>= 3.2.0)

model_tree was resolved to 1.0, which depends on
  rails
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the version of `composite_primary_keys` gem.

Change it to `~> 8.0.0` which requires activerecord '~>4.2.0'

```
gem 'composite_primary_keys',  '~> 8.0.0'
```

Refer [composite_primary_keys.gemspec](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys/blob/v8.0.0/composite_primary_keys.gemspec)

Similarly, for other gems you can do the same.

Or if you are not sure on the gem versions you can just add gem name and leave the versions for `bundler` to take care of it.